# Why do I get a false result from the following logic?

Tags: kotlin

Why do I get a false from the following logic? 
This is very simple logic. Since result is not null(ture), I thought that the result will be true.
Does anyone know why?

```
    @Test
    internal fun test() {

        val result = createBoolean()
        val recentYear : Int = 200
        val finalResult = result ?: recentYear == 200

        print(finalResult) // result is false

    }

    private fun createBoolean(): Boolean? {
        return true
    }
```

Comment: I think it's being parsed as (result ?: recentYear) == 200

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Elvis operator takes precedence over the equality operator. See the [documentation here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/grammar.html#expressions).

With the exception of algebraic operators, operator precedence varies by language, so they're hard to remember. I recommend using parentheses whenever there is any ambiguity.